# Hidden table row not displaying correct information

Tags: javascript, php

I've having some issue with the Javascript. I have a table that shows the basic information of the customer when an employee conduct a search base on the customer name. When the employee clicks on "View Sales History" the hidden table row of the particular customer's sales history will appear.

I've have no problem displaying the sales history of all the customer's returned from the search when I change the css display to "table-row". However it would only display the first customer's sales history whenever I hide the table row and include the javascript to display the hidden row.

This is what I've tried doing so far, hopefully someone can help me out here.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $id = $row["id"];
     $cfname = $row["f_name"];
     $clname = $row["l_name"];
     $cemail = $row["email"];
     $ccompany = $row["company_name"];
     $year = $row["year"];
     $product = $row["product"];
     $employee = $row["employee"];
     $status = $row["status"];
     echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$cfname.' '.$clname.'</td>
            <td>'.$cemail.'</td>    
            <td>'.$ccompany.'</td>      
            <td> <h4 id="vsalesHistory" onclick="vsalesHistory()">View Sales History</h4></td>
            </tr>';

     echo '<thead id="salesHistoryHead">
            <tr>
             <th>Date of Sales</th>
             <th>Type of Product</th>
             <th>Previous Sales Manager</th>
             <th>Job Status</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>';
    echo '<tr id="salesHistory">
            <td>'.$year.'</td>
            <td>'.$product.'</td>
            <td>'.$employee.'</td>
            <td>'.$status.'</td>
        </tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

and this is my JS script

```
function vsalesHistory(){
    var e = document.getElementById('salesHistoryHead');
    var f = document.getElementById('salesHistory');
    if(e.style.display == 'table-row'){
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        e.style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    if(f.style.display == 'table-row'){
        f.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        f.style.display = 'table-row';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple rows with the same ID, which is not a good idea. Instead, use the row ID to create unique iDs, like:

```
echo '<thead id="salesHistoryHead' . $id . '">
        <tr>
         <th>Date of Sales</th>
         <th>Type of Product</th>
         <th>Previous Sales Manager</th>
         <th>Job Status</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>';
echo '<tr id="salesHistory' . $id . '">
        <td>'.$year.'</td>
        <td>'.$product.'</td>
        <td>'.$employee.'</td>
        <td>'.$status.'</td>
    </tr>';
```

Then pass the ID with the button action, e.g.

```
        <td> <h4 id="vsalesHistory" onclick="vsalesHistory(' . $id . ')">View Sales History</h4></td>
```

If $id is a string, you would need to quote it in the call to vsalesHistory.

Now you can use the ID in your Javascript to pick the single right set of information.

For example:

```
function vsalesHistory(id){
    var e = document.getElementById('salesHistoryHead'+id);
    var f = document.getElementById('salesHistory'+id);
    ...
```

Comment: @bobdye thank you so much!! I didn't know we could assign a unique id tag in this way. Learnt something new today.